# Wildfly JDBC for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, wildfly, wildfly-10

In order to deploy an application in Wildfly I needed to setup a JDBC module for database connection so I deployed the JDBC driver

[image: deployment]

After that, I added a datasource.

The problem I found no postgresql driver:

[image: jdbc driver]

Any idea how to solve this?

I'm using Wildfly 10 and PostgreSQL 9.5 with Java 7

Comment: What is jdbc-pgsql-8? Have you renamed or changed the standard `postgresql-9.4.1212.jar` jar (latest available driver download at time of writing) in any way? This works just fine for me, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't deploy the driver as a module but as a deployment. You have to create the module manually or use the jboss-cli like this:

```
module add --name=org.postgres --resources=/tmp/postgresql-version.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api
```

Then register the module as a JDBC driver like this :

```
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=postgres:add(driver-name="postgres",driver-module-name="org.postgres",driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver)
```

Then you'll be able to create your datasource.

Comment: This is not true. I always add JDBC drivers to WildFly as deployments and it  works just fine. And it's way easier to do.

Comment: There is/was a bug though with deployed drivers showing up in the web console. I can't seem to find the JIRA though.

Comment: James was thinking about https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HAL-1228 / https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-7249

Comment: FWIW, the [WildFly DataSource Configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/DataSource+configuration) documentation has stated for some years `The recommended way to install a JDBC driver into WildFly 8 is to deploy it as a regular JAR deployment`.